# Stylus does not work with valid css

Tags: css, stylus

One of the compiling reason I was going with [stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/) was the is can work with regular css in stylus files (so I could convert as needed instead of having to convert everything at once) however that does not seem to be true.  The following .styl file:

```
.page-wrap
{
    min-height: 300px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 940px;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

compiles to this .css file:

```
.page-wrap,
{
  min-height: 300px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1;
  min-width: 940px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The extra comma at the end of the selector is invalid.

Is stylus not supposed to work with regular css or is this a bug (I am using the latest version from npm)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bug...

Comment: what is stylus? please link it.

Comment: Stylus is a CSS tool similar to less. http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/

Comment: @ryanzec https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/585#issuecomment-42783900

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a bug. Put the opening curly brace on the same line as the selector and I think it will go away.

I believe it's doing this because stylus also supports writing code without commas, semicolons etc. So it understands a line ending with no opening curly brace as an indication that you're going to add another selector on the next line, therefore it inserts a comma for you

Answer (score 2):

I [filed an issue](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/585) some time ago regarding this, and [the issue should be fixed as of 0.45.0](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/585#issuecomment-42783900).

Answer (score 0):

Stylus don't uses {} tags, you need don't use {}. Example:

```
.page-wrap,
    min-height: 300px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 940px;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-wrap
{
    min-height: 300px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 940px;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Produces

```
.page-wrap {
    min-height: 300px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 940px;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

on me. [source](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpBVwJ%20)